# Tag Helper asp-validation-for is always showing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

I tried using the Asp.Net Core TagHelper but it doesn't seem to work. However, when using HtmlHelpers it works as expected. My issue is that it always display the error message although the ModelState is valid. Am I doing something wrong or can someone reproduce this error?

```
<label class="control-label" asp-for="Firstname">Firstname</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Firstname">
<span class="form-control-feedback" asp-validation-for="Firstname"> This field has an error. </span>
```

The property `Firstname` has a `Required` attribute in the ViewModel.

It works like this:

```
<label class="control-label" asp-for="Firstname">Firstname</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Firstname">
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Firstname)
```

**Edit:**

It seems to work if I don't add the custom error message to the Html element but instead to the ViewModel DataAnnotation, like this:

```
<label class="control-label" asp-for="Firstname">Firstname</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Firstname">
<span class="form-control-feedback" asp-validation-for="Firstname"></span>
```

Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field has an error.")]
public string Firstname { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR:

Consider putting text inside the tag helpers in scenarios when you really want something
different from the generated value.

#### Full answer

You practically find the solution on your own, but I think I can still throw in my two cents here.

Most tag helpers work in a manner of generating content on a condition when its content is empty or contain only whitespace characters. For example, the [`ValidationMessageTagHelper`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/ValidationMessageTagHelper.cs#L91) checks it in this way:

```cs
var tagHelperContent = await output.GetChildContentAsync();

// We check for whitespace to detect scenarios such as:
// <span validation-for="Name">
// </span>
if (!tagHelperContent.IsEmptyOrWhiteSpace)
{
    message = tagHelperContent.GetContent();
}
```

It gets tag content and then fills up `message` variable if the content is null, empty or whitespace. The `message` variable is then used to generate the validation message:

```cs
var tagBuilder = Generator.GenerateValidationMessage(
    ViewContext,
    For.ModelExplorer,
    For.Name,
    message: message,
    tag: null,
    htmlAttributes: htmlAttributes);
```

If the `message` is `null` or empty then the [generator](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/DefaultHtmlGenerator.cs) will provide the model error (see [line 858](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/DefaultHtmlGenerator.cs#L858) of `DefaultHtmlGenerator`);

```cs
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
{
    tagBuilder.InnerHtml.SetContent(message);
}
else if (modelError != null)
{
    modelExplorer = modelExplorer ?? ExpressionMetadataProvider.FromStringExpression(
        expression,
        viewContext.ViewData,
        _metadataProvider);
    tagBuilder.InnerHtml.SetContent(
        ValidationHelpers.GetModelErrorMessageOrDefault(modelError, entry, modelExplorer));
}
```

The [`GetModelErrorMessageOrDefault()`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/ValidationHelpers.cs#L37) of [`ValidationHelpers`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/ValidationHelpers.cs):

```cs
public static string GetModelErrorMessageOrDefault(
    ModelError modelError,
    ModelStateEntry containingEntry,
    ModelExplorer modelExplorer)
{
    Debug.Assert(modelError != null);
    Debug.Assert(containingEntry != null);
    Debug.Assert(modelExplorer != null);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modelError.ErrorMessage))
    {
        return modelError.ErrorMessage;
    }

    // Default in the ValidationMessage case is a fallback error message.
    var attemptedValue = containingEntry.AttemptedValue ?? "null";
    return modelExplorer.Metadata.ModelBindingMessageProvider.ValueIsInvalidAccessor(attemptedValue);
}
```

So yes, if you put any text inside the `<span>` validation tag, the tag helper will choose your text over validation error from model state. Similar behaviour occurs if you put text inside the `<label`> tag as you did:

```html
<label class="control-label" asp-for="Firstname">Firstname</label>
```

The tag helper will not overwrite the `Firstname` value you put inside the tag. It may not seem as bad behaviour, but if you would like to use display name for the `Firstname` property:

```cs
[Display(Name = "Fancy first name")]
public string Firstname { get; set; }
```

you **would not** see it work! Because the tag helper would again choose the text you put in-between `<label>` tags over the display name for `Firstname`.

What you should do is leave it as simple as i can be:

```html
<label class="control-label" asp-for="Firstname"></label>
```

Consider putting text inside the tag helpers in scenarios when you really want something
different from the generated value.

At the begging I said that most tag helpers work that way. Most of them do, but not all of them. For example `SelectTagHelper` allows you to put any custom text inside the tag and if you provide a select list, it will generate the options by appending them to the existing content. It is extremely handy for adding custom `<option>` tags. For example I can easily add a selected and disabled option, so the dropdown does not have initial value, therefore the user is forced to manually select an option. These lines of code:

```html
<select asp-for="LevelId" asp-items="@Model.Levels" class="custom-select">
    <option selected disabled>Select option</option>
</select>
```

will result in:

```html
<select class="custom-select" data-val="true" data-val-required="&#x27;Level Id&#x27; must not be empty." id="LevelId" name="LevelId">
    <option selected disabled>Select parking level</option>
    <option value="9">-2</option>
    <option value="8">-1</option>
    <option value="7">0</option>
</select>
```